# How to connect via ipv4 to ipv6 only OpenVpn?

Tags: routing, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi, ipv6, ipv4

I want to use my Raspberry Pi as an OpenVPN Server to connect from everywhere to my home network. My ISP provides me only with an IPv6 address, so I can only access the OpenVPN via IPv4. Unfortunately the rest of the world is still kinda stuck with IPv4, so is there anyway I can still connect using an IPv4 address to my Raspberry Pi?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Most ISPs will still provide an unshared IPv4 address to business customers, with a corresponding increase in the monthly service charge (tariff). But even this won't last forever. Everyone must adopt IPv6 sooner or later, and your situation is one reason why. The world has run out of available IPv4 addresses, and any that remain available for new customers are going to be scrounged from Gawd knows where. This will only get worse, and will never get better.

Comment: So basically I'm screwed and can just patiently wait for wonders to happen (or rent a VPS somewhere instead of using my Raspberry Pi…)

Comment: If a VPS with an IPv4 address costs less than upgrading to business Internet service, and you can stand the latency, then yes... At that point you may as well get a VPS with both IPv4 and IPv6, make it the VPN server, and then you can VPN into it and have IPv6 anywhere with which to connect back to your home.

Comment: @MichaelHampton In order for that to work properly you need a VPS with a routed IPv6 prefix. Not all VPS providers will give you that.

Comment: @kasperd Ideally yes, but you can run an NDP proxy to get around that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have tried that, it worked great for a while. Then one day the provider turned on ND snooping without warning, and things stopped working.